# If $B$ is a $C^*$-subalgebra of $A$, then $\sigma_A(b) \cup \{0\} = \sigma_B(b) \cup \{0\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, solution-verification, c-star-algebras

In Murphy's book on $C^*$-algebras, it is claimed that f $B$ is a $C^*$-subalgebra of a $C^*$-algebra $A$, then $\sigma_A(b) \cup \{0\} = \sigma_B(b) \cup \{0\}$.

Denote the unitalisation of $A$ by $\tilde{A}$.

To prove this, I will freely use the following results:

(1) If $A$  is a unital algebra and $B$ a subalgebra with $B + \Bbb{C}1_A = A$, then $\sigma_B(b) \cup \{0\} = \sigma_A(b) \cup \{0\}$ for $b \in B$.

(2) If $A$ is a unital $C^*$-algebra and $B$ is a $C^*$-subalgebra with $1_A \in B$, then $\sigma_A(b) =\sigma_B(b)$ for $b \in B$.

**My attempt**:

Case 1: $A$ is unital.

If $1_A \in B$, we are done by $(2)$.
So suppose that $1_A \notin B$. Then we have
$$\sigma_B(b) \cup \{0\} \stackrel{(1)}= \sigma_{B \oplus\Bbb{C}1_A}(b) \cup \{0\}$$
$$\stackrel{(2)}=\sigma_A(b) \cup \{0\}$$

Case 2: $A$ is non-unital. Then
$$\sigma_A(b) \cup \{0\}=\sigma_{\tilde{A}}(b) \cup \{0\}$$

However, $\tilde{A}$ is a unital $C^*$-algebra and since $A$ is a $C^*$-subalgebra of $\tilde{A}$, we also have that $B$ is a $C^*$-subalgebra of $\tilde{A}$. Consequently, by case $(1)$ we get
$$\sigma_{\tilde{A}}(b) \cup \{0\} = \sigma_B(b) \cup \{0\}$$

and we can conclude the proof. $\quad \square$

Is the above proof correct?

Comment: If you have those two statements then there is basically nothing left to prove. Directly apply them to the situation as you have done. The proof is correct.

Comment: Your proof is correct, however the fact that you proof is so short in comparison with the proofs given in any book relies in the actually not trivial statement (2). Some teacher told me once that if a proof of a not trivial fact is easy, it is because we are hiding the trash somewhere haha.